# Can't delete a file

Tags: rm

I tried to use

```
sudo rm -rf .Trash-1001
```

But it says

```
The Removing of .Trash-1001/info" is not possible: The directory is not empty.
```

(This is a translation by me because I have German as my system language)

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Delete a paricular file or entire folder ?

Comment: The entire folder

Comment: can you provide more details, path of directory and what directory you need to remove ?

Comment: It's under /media/user/myHDD/ The directory is called .Trash-1000. That's the folder wher things go when i delete something on this drive.

Comment: Are there any processes (like a terminal or she'll) that are cd'd to a subdirectory of that path?

Comment: If you're using `sudo rm -rf` *before* trying anything else, I really hope you have a backup.  Do you use a shotgun to kill houseflies?

Comment: I am not using a shotgun to kill houseflies, i'm not an american.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem with locked files in the `.Trash` directory?

See [this Apple support post](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201583), which suggests running

```
chflags -R nouchg ...
```

on the trash directory before attempting `rm -rf`.